# Is it possible to lock excel sheet leaving group outline feature unlocked in apache poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have created the below sample using apache poi

[image]

using the following code

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static final String file = "C:\\Users\\Deepak\\IdeaProjects\\Test\\src\\main\\resources\\test.xlsx";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("sheet1");
        for(int row = 0;row < 10;row++) {
            Row rowI = sheet.createRow(row);
            Cell cell = rowI.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue("cell"+row+'0');
        }
        sheet.groupRow(1, 5);
        sheet.setRowGroupCollapsed(1, true);
        sheet.protectSheet("dummy");
        workbook.write(new FileOutputStream(new File(file)));
    }
}
```

The sheet is locked but the collapse(+) feature is also locked. I don't want the collapse button to be locked. Is there a way to solve this problem?

I googled this but didn't find anything for apache POI. I found a solution for VBA [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other-mso_2007/enable-groupungroup-in-protected-sheet/b6d506dc-14fd-402a-99bb-ac208861950f) and tried to find a similar method (enableOutlining) in apache poi but didn't find any.

I am using Apache POI 3.9

Any help/guidance will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. There is no setting to enable outlining while sheet is protected. At least not one which is stored in the file.

There is [Worksheet.EnableOutlining](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.enableoutlining). But this only can be set if sheet protection is set `UserInterfaceOnly:=True`. And that means that the protection is active only while the workbook is opened in `Excel`'s `GUI`.

See http://www.spreadsheet1.com/outlining.html. And also [Excel: EnableOutlining seems to default to False on opening workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983622/excel-enableoutlining-seems-to-default-to-false-on-opening-workbook).

Conclusion: Only possible if the workbook contains `VBA` and is able to run macros and runs that `VBA` protection code while `Workbook_Open()`.